# Android (detect external sd card) isExternalStorageRemovable is possible with AS3 Adobe Air?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, sd-card, air-native-extension

In Android SDK we can detect External sd card with,

```
Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();
```

or

```
 Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated();
```

I want to know if it is possible with Adobe Air Android SDK (3.2 or above)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is an equivalent method with the AIR SDK. However it is possible to develop "AIR Native Extensions (ANEs)" to give you access to methods available in the native environment. You can find many tutorials on the net, but I recommend starting [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this might work on Android, but anyway

```
import flash.filesystem.StorageVolume;
import flash.filesystem.StorageVolumeInfo;

var volumes = StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo.getStorageVolumes(); 
for (var i = 0; i < volumes.length; i++) 
{ 
    var volume:StorageVolume = volumes[i];
    trace ("isRemovable :" + volume.isRemovable);
}
```

Though can't remember somethin like this,

```
Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated();
```

IMHO you might need ANE anyway.

Comment: I have already tested `StorageVolumeInfo` and it doesn't work with Android. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work:

**isExternalStorageRemovable()**

```
public static boolean isExternalStorageRemovable() {
    String val = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    if (val == null) {
        return false;
    }
    File microSd = null;
    String[] arr = val.split(":");
    for (String path : arr) {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            microSd = file;
            break;
        }
    }
    return microSd != null;
}
```

**isExternalStorageEmulated()**

```
public static boolean isExternalStroageEmulated() {
    return System.getEnv("EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE") != null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it for AS3 and not for Andriod SDK Java.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Well, if you can check environmental variables then you can adapt the code and it should work.